# How to create a table value function script in a DACPAC SQL Server project?

Tags: sql-server, dacpac

I have a DACPAC SQL Server project that I edit in Visual Studio. I then have a SQL script for a table value function. How can I then embed the SQL script into the DACPAC project? I can't find any tutorial on how to make the folder and folder name, and how to set up the SQL file.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Creating folders isn't actually a requirement.  When you build the project all objects represented in the project file will be added to the resulting DACPAC.  Folders are merely a way to organize your files.

Generally speaking, your folder structure within the SQL DB project will look something like this:

```
Schema1
  Functions
    SomeFunc.sql
    OtherFunc.sql
  Stored Procedures
    SomeProc.sql
    OtherProc.sql
  Tables
    SomeTable.sql
    OtherTable.sql
  Views
    SomeView.sql
    OtherView.sql

Schema2
  Functions
    SomeFunc.sql
    OtherFunc.sql
  Stored Procedures
    SomeProc.sql
    OtherProc.sql
  Tables
    SomeTable.sql
    OtherTable.sql
  Views
    SomeView.sql
    OtherView.sql
. . . etc . . .
```

NOTE: if you create your function in a SQL Server DB, you can then jump back into Visual Studio and use Tools >> SQL Server >> Schema Compare to import your function into the project.  Visual Studio will create the folders for you.

Comment: The sql file has this stuff on the top `SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO` and `GO` on  the bottom. Are these things I can remove when putting in the DACPAC?